# Filling a 5x5 grid with {0,1,2} such that each diagonal contains the same elements typewise

Tags: grid-deduction

[Technothlon 2018 Hauts Section, Q17](https://www.technothlon.techniche.org.in/downloads/prevpapers):

[image: This question was asked in an exam called Technothlon in 2019]

Consider arrays of integers, a(ij) with the following property. For all pairs of distinct rows il,i2 and distinct columns jl,j2 the diagonal sum asil,jl)+a(i2,j2) and the anti-diagonal sum asil,j2)+a(i2,jl) are unequal. We are interested in finding such arrays with the entries chosen from as narrow a range of integers as possible. For example the following is an example of such a 3x3 array with entries chosen from {0,1}
001 010
100 Find a 5x5 array with this property with entries chosen from {0,1,2). Consider all such arrays possible. There exists some (maybe one) such arrays with the property that their both main diagonals contain type-wise(0,1 or 2) the same no. of elements. Give the number of non-zero elements in any one of the main diagonals of such an array
A. 1 B.2 C. 3 D. 4

I tried to solve this question for a smaller grid. I was able to prove it wouldn't work in a 3x3 grid because if we try to make the elements the same type-wise it would violate the first rule. I'm not able to make a 4x4 grid for this. How should I proceed?

This question was asked in Technothlon in 2018

Comment: It's funny that the first paragraph has nothing to do with the rest of the problem.

Comment: I cannot find which Technothlon paper the question is from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is something in the rules for the matrix that has to be constructed that I completely misunderstand, I think this question is unanswerable.

This can be seen by looking at a solution for the 4 x 4 version of the problem, given by the matrix below. This is a solution with two zeros and two non-zeros on the diagonal. However by just swapping all zeros and ones in the matrix, we get an equally good solution with one zero and three non-zeros on the diagonal.

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

This argument can be extended to the 5 x 5 case. If we could find a solution for that problem, because the number of diagonal elements is odd, swapping zeros with either ones or twos would always lead to a solution with a different number of zeros (and therefore also non-zeros) on the diagonal.

I might have completely missed something here (the answer model for the Technothlon gives C as the correct answer), but at least to me the reasoning seems sound.

Comment: I did a computer search for 5x5.  There are plenty of matrices satisfying all the conditions.  The number of zeroes in the diagonals can be any value from 0 to 4.  The only striking constant is that all rows and columns always contain (0,0,1,2,2), in some order.  Unfortunately it doesn't apply to the diagonals.